# Panel doesn't expand in wxPython

Tags: wxpython, boxsizer

I have a problem with the following code that I don't understand.

**Why is the `panel1` not expanding?**

Thanks.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, mytitle, mysize):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, mytitle, size=mysize)
        panel1 = wx.Panel(self)
        panel2 = wx.Panel(self)
        panel3 = wx.Panel(self)

        panel1.SetBackgroundColour("green")
        panel2.SetBackgroundColour("yellow")
        panel3.SetBackgroundColour("red")

        sizer_h = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_v = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        st1 = wx.StaticText(panel1, -1, "TEST")
        sizer_h.Add(st1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer_v.Add(sizer_h, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        sizer_v.Add(panel2, proportion=2, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        sizer_v.Add(panel3, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        # only set the main sizer if you have more than one
        self.SetSizer(sizer_v)

app = wx.App()
mytitle = "wx.Frame & wx.Panels"
width = 300
height = 320
MyFrame(None, mytitle, (width, height)).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2):

The line you need to modify is:

`sizer_h.Add(st1, 1, wx.EXPAND)`

Should be:

`sizer_h.Add(panel1, 1, wx.EXPAND)`

Because you need to size the panel1 and not only the string.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add the panel to sizer_h, not st1.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, mytitle, mysize):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, mytitle, size=mysize)
        panel1 = wx.Panel(self)
        panel2 = wx.Panel(self)
        panel3 = wx.Panel(self)

        panel1.SetBackgroundColour("green")
        panel2.SetBackgroundColour("yellow")
        panel3.SetBackgroundColour("red")

        sizer_h = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_v = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        st1 = wx.StaticText(panel1, -1, "TEST")
        sizer_h.Add(panel1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer_v.Add(sizer_h, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        sizer_v.Add(panel2, proportion=2, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        sizer_v.Add(panel3, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        # only set the main sizer if you have more than one
        self.SetSizer(sizer_v)

app = wx.App()
mytitle = "wx.Frame & wx.Panels"
width = 300
height = 320
MyFrame(None, mytitle, (width, height)).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

You can now see that the panel expands to the full width of its sizer, and the height of the static text, and that the rest is occupied by a blank space. Not too sure how to vertically fill out the panel too so that no grey leaks through, sorry